# Is my question too basic for dba?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I feel my question [Minimizing the number of parent rows for a distinct column in a child table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17554/minimizing-the-number-of-parent-rows-for-a-distinct-column-in-a-child-table) may be too simple for dba. I know it is likely some simple group by logic that I am missing but I feel this is a little more complex than "join two tables together" so I am unsure of what to do. Should I remove my question and re-ask it on SO?

Comment: No, it's not basic at all. I spent 3 mins to read through your code and understand what it is trying to do. Basic would mean less than 1 minute :)

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a good question for DBA.  Mostly the "too basic" label would apply to simple operators.  The most common example I can think of is a few times a week someone asks a variation on conditional counts  that are trivially solved with a `SUM(CASE WHEN...`.

Your question is fairly complicated and specific - it's not likely someone who knows a little SQL from working on PHP will be able to resolve it for you.

That being said, you could probably have posted it on SO, but I don't think you would be likely to get any feedback.  I think DBA is the right place for it.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, many seemingly expert programmers struggle to understand set theory and how to use SQL to generate the sets of data they need.

DBA should be a place where this theory and practice can be learned by (good) example.

Comment: +1 this is so true - procedural and set-based are two quite different mindsets