# Is the comment-only answer acceptable?

Tags: discussion, faq, comments

I've just read a post that's **really** mundane. It's one of those ["*just read the error message*" type questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions). There's an obvious, correct, and incredibly trivial answer I can respond with; but I'm not sure the original post is high-quality enough to deserve a full post in reply. So...

**Is the comment-only answer ever constructive?**

**If yes, under what circumstances should it be used?**

[Prior related discussion in the meta](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2811/68127)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## No

- Questions that are trivial enough to be answered in this way are [too simple for dba.se](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/643/68127) and should be closed.
- If it does warrant a full answer, posting the answer as a comment makes the solution less discoverable for future visitors.
- Comment-answers make life harder for people trying to use comments for their [intended purposes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).
- Answering a "poor" question in a comment encourages another poor question instead of improving the current one. After all, it worked!
- Answering in a comment misleads new users into thinking it's OK to do that in general.
- Comments only support upvotes, which award no reputation. The only way to point out an incorrect comment-answer is to add another comment.
- Comments can't be improved by others (e.g. to add detail or maintain information over time). Comments can only be edited by the original author for a short time (currently 5 minutes).
- Comments have no public revision history (like answers do).
- Comment answers may dissuade others from writing a more detailed answer along the same lines.
- Comments are more easily deleted than answers.

Answer (score -5):

## Yes

- If it's a good enough question, [Paul White's comment sock](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/179?m=53173795#53173795) (or some other good samaritan) will convert it to an answer at some point anyway.
- It makes it [easier to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/299676) the question in the future if it's deemed to be clutter.
- We don't alienate a new user. They still get an answer and a chance to reply asking for further help. <sup>*They can always learn more about the site by self-posting an answer as well!*</sup>

Comment: I created Comment Converter as way to *show* people how much better answers are in answers than comments. It is not intended to be used as a service (it is time consuming). Why make work for others? Answering in comments does new users a disservice by illustrating how *not* to do things!